# Firefox warnings

Tags: command-line, firefox

I am getting these warnings while launching firefox from a terminal:

```
(process:4049): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:4049): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:4049): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:4049): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:4049): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
```

Comment: It is a BUG - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1160569

Comment: But then..how to fix this bug??

Comment: You have to wait for a bug fix. In the meantime use an alternate browser (sorry)

Comment: A different version may work - either install a different version, or compile one - see [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux)

Comment: Or, ignore the false error messages.

Comment: If it works, it should be fine... :-) - you don't get 'false' error messages, just mostly unnecessary ones